# What is the direct sum of a singleton and an interval?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, definition

Let $\{a \}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

What does it mean for $\{a\} \oplus A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors of the form $a + a'$ for $a' \in A$ where $a$ not in $ A$.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectSum.html

Comment: Why $a \notin A$ ?

Comment: For instance, what would be $\{-1\} \oplus [-1,1]$?

Comment: the direct sum applies to vector subspaces with empty intersection.

Answer (score 1):

As the question is tagged *general-topology*, I assume we are to take the direct sum in the category **Top** of topological spaces and continuous maps. In that case, "direct sum" is simply "disjoint union". So if $a$ is not in the closure of $A$, we can simply take $X=A\cup\{a\}$; otherwise or just to be on the safe side, take $X=A\cup\{\alpha\}$, where $\alpha$ is a symbol that is not even $\in\Bbb R$ and declare $U\subseteq X$ open iff $U\cap A$ is open.